# Rust: Unicode-aware string matching

Tags: rust, unicode

I want to determine if some string contains a certain substring while respecting combining characters. To illustrate the problem, consider the following example in Rust:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a_umlaut = "a\u{0308}"; // "ä"
    println!("{}", a_umlaut.starts_with("a")); // true
}
```

Basically, the above shows that `"ä".starts_with("a")` is true (note the diaeresis over the first "a"). I do understand the reason for this behavior on a technical level, but I still want the above code to output `false`, since "ä" and "a" are two different user-perceived characters.

Is there an existing function/create that performs string matching while respecting combining characters?

Comment: The typical way to do this AIUI is to normalize both the needle and the haystack, and then execute the search. The benefit of this approach is that it scales to any sort of substring matching you want, without.having to tailor the implementation to be aware of Unicode normal forms.

Comment: @BurntSushi5 Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think normalization helps in this case. In the above example, both needle and haystack are NFD-normalized. The problem is that the character-wise comparison performed by Rust does not take into account that the `"a"` in the haystack is not actually an `"a"` because it is modified by the combining character `"\u{0308}"`.

Comment: You could try this lib: https://crates.io/crates/unicode-segmentation

Comment: @AngelicosPhosphoros Hm, yes, I think I could just compare the graphemes of both strings. I believe this should give intuitive results. Thanks for the hint! However, I'm still curious if this is the generally accepted way to do this (it seems so, since I was talking about user-perceived characters, and graphemes seem to be just that).

Comment: I didn't even know such a problem exists. :(

Comment: Maybe https://docs.rs/unicode-normalization/0.1.19/unicode_normalization/ ?

Comment: Just for the record, the letter "ä" can be represented in two different ways in Unicode -- either as in the question with an "a" together with a"combining diaresis", or as the single codepoint `"\u{00e4}"`. If Unicode normalisation ends up normalising to the two-codepoint version, it won't solve this problem, so normalising both needle and haystack isn't a full solution.

Comment: @SvenMarnach There are four Unicode normalization forms, NFD, NKD, NFC, NKC. If you normalize the strings into NFC or NKC then combining characters will be combined into a singe codepoint.

Comment: Right. You want one of the composed normal forms for prefix matching. Grapheme clusters are perhaps another route that might be easy to do for prefix matching specifically, but you would need something specifically tailored to it for arbitrary substring searches (or perhaps a generic implementation of substring search, which are pretty uncommon) while maintaining good time/space complexity guarantees.

Comment: @Stuart The problem is that only _some_ combined characters can be represented as single codepoints, while others can't, so even the combining normal forms won't fully solve the problem, though the approach is probably good enough in many practical situations.

Comment: If the list of modifiers is small-ish (under 10) I would think that this is one of the times for a regex, something similar to `^a[^ModifiersToExclude]` (if regex is wrong, sue me, but you get the idea) so you're finding only an unadorned `a` character.  And of course that won't match a combined code point as it's just not the same first part.  If the list of modifiers explodes though, then this becomes impractical.

Answer (score 0):

I expanded out my idea from my comment.  This regular expression will match at the beginning of a string, an `a` character without an umlaut.

```rust
use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    let a_umlaut = "a\u{0308}"; // "ä"
    println!("Original string: {}", a_umlaut);
    println!("Start with regular 'a': {}", a_umlaut.starts_with("a")); // true

    let re = Regex::new(r"^a[^\u{0308}]").unwrap(); // Matches non-combined "a" at the front
    tester(&re, a_umlaut);      // "a" with umlaut behind
    tester(&re, "blessed are"); // "a" in the middle, not the front
    tester(&re, "amore!");      // "a" at the front

}

fn tester(re: &Regex, test: &str)
{
    println!("For string: '{}' with Regex: '{}', match is: {}", test, re.as_str(), re.is_match(test));
}
```

Output:

```
Original string: ä
Start with regular 'a': true
For string: 'ä' with Regex: '^a[^\u{0308}]', match is: false
For string: 'blessed are' with Regex: '^a[^\u{0308}]', match is: false
For string: 'amore!' with Regex: '^a[^\u{0308}]', match is: true
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9d949687ab317c0defa55dfd916d1e62)

The idea here is that you could expand the list of characters you do *not* want to match for inside the regex, so anything that would combine with `a` would also be listed.  This *does* run into the problem that this could be a very long list, but if this is a constrained problem, this approach could work.

Comment: Thank you for your work! I think the idea is good, but I'm not sure regex are a good fit because Unicode defines a large number of combining characters which would all have to be excluded in the regex (as you already point out). However, one could instead directly check (using the Unicode data tables) whether the character following the "a" is a combining character. Alternatively, one could also compare graphemes instead of characters, which should avoid the whole problem with combining characters. I try to post some kind of solution using this approach soon.